# Как настроить иерархию в ссылке? WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, чпу

Woocommerce дает возможность сгенерировать ссылки на продукт трех типов:

- https://sitelink/product/sample-product/
- https://sitelink/shop/sample-product/
- https://sitelink/shop/product-category/sample-product/

Мне же нужна ссылки формата: 
https://sitelink/product-category/product-sub-category/sample-product
с возможностью бесконечной вложенности подкатегорий.

Как такое реализовать, может кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть плагин [WooCommerce Permalink Manager.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-permalink-manager/)